# Can't See SQLite Files Copied to User iCloud Drive

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, swiftui, icloud

In a SwiftUI app with Core Data I am trying to copy the sqlite files to the user iCloud Drive. While the code below says the files were written and exist in a directory that I created, I am not able to see them in the Files app on a physical device, nor in Finder under the iCloud Drive of the user (me in this case). I have reviewed several SO articles about this and I have tried to follow recommendations, but I must be missing something.

iCloud documents is enabled, with a container for this app alone. The info.plist has been updated as follows:

[image: ,]

The code below will run as is, if a .sqlite file is added to the Bundle.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var message = "Not yet configured."

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
        
            Button {
            
                let docName = "artworkd"
                let docExt = "sqlite"
            
                copyFileToDocumentsFolder(nameForFile: docName, extForFile: docExt)
                message = ""
            } label: {
                Text("Load SQL file into Documents Folder")
            }
        
            Button(action: {
                let fileList = getDocumentsFolderContents()
                message = "\(fileList[0])"
            }, label: {
                Text("Print Documents Folder Contents")
            })
        
            Text("Message:")
            Text(message)
        
            Button(action: {
                copyFileToiCloudDocuments()
                message = ""
            }, label: {
                Text("Copy File to iCloud")
            })
        
            Button(action: {
                copyFileToiCloudSQL()
                message = ""
            }, label: {
                Text("Copy File to iCloud SQL")
            })
        
            Button(action: {
                let files = getSQLContents()
                message = files.first?.absoluteString ?? "No files returned"
            
            }, label: {
                Text("Get SQL Contents")
            })
        }
        .padding()
    }//body

    func copyFileToDocumentsFolder(nameForFile: String, extForFile: String) {
    
        let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
        let destURL = documentsURL!.appendingPathComponent(nameForFile).appendingPathExtension(extForFile)
    
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destURL.path) {
            print("file already exists in documents folder")
        
            do {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: destURL.path)
                print("file deleted from documents folder")
            } catch {
                print("error deleting file", error.localizedDescription)
            }
        } else {
            print("file does not exist in documents folder")
        }
        guard let sourceURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: nameForFile, withExtension: extForFile)
        else {
            print("Source File not found.")
            return
        }
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        do {
            try fileManager.copyItem(at: sourceURL, to: destURL)
            print("file copied to documents folder")
        } catch {
            print("Unable to copy file")
        }
    }//copy file to docs

    func getDocumentsFolderContents() -> [URL] {
    
        let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first! as URL
    
        var fullFileNames: [URL] = []
        var shortFileNames: [String] = []
    
        do {
            let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
        
            for f in directoryContents {
                fullFileNames.append(f)
                shortFileNames.append(f.lastPathComponent)
            }
        
            print("shortFileNames:")
            print(shortFileNames)
        
        } catch {
            print("Error while enumerating files \(documentsURL.path): \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    
        return fullFileNames
    
    }//get documents folder contents

    func getSQLContents() -> [URL] {
        guard let iCloudDocumentsURL = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)?.appendingPathComponent("Documents") else { return []}
    
        let iCloudSQLURL = iCloudDocumentsURL.appendingPathComponent("SQL")
    
        var fullFileNames: [URL] = []
        var shortFileNames: [String] = []
    
        do {
            let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: iCloudSQLURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
        
            for f in directoryContents {
                fullFileNames.append(f)
                shortFileNames.append(f.lastPathComponent)
            }
        
            print("shortFileNames:")
            print(shortFileNames)
        
        } catch {
            print("Error while enumerating files \(iCloudSQLURL.path): \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    
        return fullFileNames
    
    }//get documents folder contents

    func copyFileToiCloudDocuments() {
    
        if let iCloudDocumentsURL = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)?.appendingPathComponent("Documents") {
        
            do {
                try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: iCloudDocumentsURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true)
                print("Documents directory created")
            } catch {
                print("error creating Documents directory", error.localizedDescription)
            }
        
            do {
                guard let answer = getDocumentsFolderContents().first else { return }
                let dataFromFile = try Data(contentsOf: answer)
                print(dataFromFile.count)
            
                try dataFromFile.write(to: iCloudDocumentsURL.appendingPathComponent("mything.sqlite", conformingTo: .data))
                print("file written")
            } catch {
                print("error copying file to icloud")
            }
        
        }//if let iCloudDocumentsURL
    
    }//copy file to icloud

    func copyFileToiCloudSQL() {
    
        if let iCloudDocumentsURL = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)?.appendingPathComponent("Documents") {
        
            do {
                try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: iCloudDocumentsURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true)
                print("Documents directory created")
            } catch {
                print("error creating Documents directory", error.localizedDescription)
            }
        
            let iCloudSQLURL = iCloudDocumentsURL.appendingPathComponent("SQL", isDirectory: true)
        
            do {
                try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: iCloudSQLURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true)
                print("SQL directory created")
            } catch {
                print("error creating SQL directory", error.localizedDescription)
            }
        
            do {
                guard let answer = getDocumentsFolderContents().first else { return }
                let dataFromFile = try Data(contentsOf: answer)
                print(dataFromFile.count)
            
                try dataFromFile.write(to: iCloudSQLURL.appendingPathComponent("mything.sqlite", conformingTo: .data))
                print("file seems to have been written")
            } catch {
                print("error copying file to icloud")
            }
        
        }//if no sql directory
    
    }//copy file to icloud

}//struct
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. Xcode 15 Beta 8, iOS 17 but I am not using any new features of Xcode or iOS.